# Debugging PHP/Zend Framework web apps

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, doctrine

i am using Zend Framework. some techniques i use currently

- `Zend_Debug::dump()` (+`die()`)
- `Zend_Log`: to firebug/firephp

i particularly like the log to firebug, but when logging large objects, eg. doctrine 2 models (with many associated objects etc), i find that it slows down and crashes alot.

what alternatives are out there?

i currently use Notepad++, used Aptana Studio 3 b4, waiting for more php support, i think netbeans can debug php scripts is it? the step through debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following IDEs support step through debugging:

- eclipse (PDT)

  - Aptana Studio
  - Zend Studio
- Netbeans

Note: Aptana Studio and Zend Studio are based on eclipse.